# Programar um teste para checar se existem bibliotecas no "package.json" do tipo "@types/..." que estão no local incorreto. É possível?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

Já peguei diversas vezes no `package.json` bibliotecas `"@types/..."` em `"dependencies"` em vez de estar `"devDependencies"`.

É que elas foram instaladas sem adicionar o parâmetro `-D` durante o `yarn add`. Erros acontecem e isso é completamente normal.

Alguns devs acabam instalando a dependência de forma incorreta e fica chato ficar exigindo deles repetidas vezes para tomar este cuidado.

O VS Code aqui não exibe nenhuma mensagem de alerta quando isto está assim.

Então seria possível programar um teste no VS Code para checar se há dependências `"@types/..."` que estão em `"dependencies"` mas que deveriam estar `"devDependencies"` utilizando TypeScript?

E caso existam bibliotecas que estão no local incorreto, exibir uma mensagem de alerta no console PROBLEMS do VS Code tipo:

```
A biblioteca "@types/..." está no local incorreto no "package.json"! Ela deveria estar em "devDependencies" em vez de "dependencies".
A biblioteca "@types/..." está no local incorreto no "package.json"! Ela deveria estar em "devDependencies" em vez de "dependencies".
```

Como a mensagem de alerta precisa estar em inglês, talvez poderia ficar assim:

```
The library "@types / ..." is in the wrong location in "package.json"! It should be in "devDependencies" instead of "dependencies".
The library "@types / ..." is in the wrong location in "package.json"! It should be in "devDependencies" instead of "dependencies".
```

(Estou arriscando no inglês! Me perdoem! )

Caso os devs não tome este cuidado podem existir várias bibliotecas no deploy da aplicação sem haver necessidade.
O deploy fica até mais lento por causa disso!

É possível programar isto? Ou isto já existe?

Faz sentido programar isto no VS Code a fim de ajudar os devs a tomarem este tipo de cuidado?

Comment: Eu sinceramente acho que isso nada tem a ver com o propósito do ESLint. Como o próprio nome diz, "ECMAScript Lint". E isso, pelo menos na minha concepção, não me parece ser uma responsabilidade do ESLint, já que isso não se trata da _linguagem_ ECMAScript (vulgo JavaScript) em si, mas sim do _ambiente_ de desenvolvimento. O que mais me parece adequado é criar um script [`postinstall`](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/lifecycle-scripts) que roda um script qualquer para fazer essa verificação. Outra possibilidade é delegar isso para algo como um CI, mas aí já me parece um certo exagero.

Comment: @LuizFelipe

Realmente vc tem razão! Obrigado! 
O ESLint não é para verificar arquivos JSON.

_ESLint é uma ferramenta de análise de código estático para identificar padrões problemáticos encontrados no código JavaScript._

Vou editar o enunciado da pergunta removendo o termo "ESLint". Tudo bem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você tiver um *script* `test` no seu `package.json`, pode criar um outro chamado `pretest`, que sempre será executado automaticamente *antes* do `test`, ou `posttest`, que será executado *depois* de `test` (também automaticamente).

Assim, sempre que (antes ou depois) um teste for executado, você pode fazer essa verificação.

No `package.json`, algo assim:

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "<seu-script-de-testes>",
    "pretest": "node check-deps.js"
  },
  // ...
}
```

<sup>Note que utilizamos `pretest`, o que executará o *script* `check-deps.js` *antes* dos testes.</sup>

E no `check-deps.js`, pode fazer algo assim:

```
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');

const pkgPath = join(process.cwd(), 'package.json');
const { dependencies } = JSON.parse(readFileSync(pkgPath, 'utf8'));

if (typeof dependencies !== 'object') {
  process.exit(0);
}

let warned = false;
for (const depName of Object.keys(dependencies)) {
  if (depName.startsWith('@types/')) {
    if (!warned) {
      warned = true;
    }

    console.error(
      `Dependência "${depName}" deveria estar no campo \`devDependencies\`, e não \`dependencies\`.`
    );
  }
}

process.exit(warned ? 1 : 0);
```

Se você quiser fazer algo mais ligado ao VSCode, pode tentar [criar uma extensão](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension).

Answer (score 0):

Acreditamos que não há uma possibilidade concreta para fazer isto, pois, vamos pensar no seguinte caso. O nosso arquivo que contém a referência das bibliotecas, é o `package.json`, certo? E nele, contém várias propriedades como:

```
author:...
license:...
version:...
```

Logo, logicamente, o certo seria algo como, localizar o arquivo `package.json`, acessar o arquivo, procurar nas `dependencies` se existe algum `@types`, se sim, verificar se existe o `devDependencies`, caso exista, lançar um warning dizendo para ele instalar a biblioteca de tipagens em modo de desenvolvimento.
Acredito que teria que fazer algo como os `streams`, que podemos acessar e etc...

Comment: VagnerWentz obrigado pela resposta.  Entendo. O ```package.json``` é uma arquivo JSON fácil fácil de ler e de manipular os dados com qualquer linguagem de programação. A questão é esta: _É possível programar este teste encima do VS Code?_ Seria tipo: _"Como criar meus testes customizados no VS Code"_. Talvez seja até possível de utilizar o próprio TypeScript para criar esse teste customizado.  Depois vou pesquisar esse assunto nos sites do exterior.
(Atualizado conforme a sugestão do @LuizFelipe)

Comment: @DeividsonDamasio Entendi, acredito que sim, é possível fazer, mas da minha opinião, acredito que isto deixa o programador mais "preguiçoso". Porque de fato, programador que está usando TypeScript por exemplo, ele sabe que bibliotecas de `@types` devem sim ser em modo de desenvolvimento. Mas talvez procurando mais a fundo, encontre uma resposta melhor. Mas super interessante a sua dúvida. Vou correr atrás para ver se acho algo parecido.

Comment: VagnerWentz entendo. Mas eu não quero deixar o dev "preguiçoso".  Desejo apenas exibir uma mensagem de erro no console *PROBLEMS* do VS Code a fim de mostrá-lo que existe uma correção para ser efetuada no ```package.json```. Compreendeu?
Também estou pesquisando aqui. Obrigado. 